# Me da este error en la bd ""Error de sentencia SQL: Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, api, mariadb

En MySQL tengo 2 tablas, la tabla paciente esta relacionada con la otra patologias; patologias tiene el campo id que es autoincremental, nombre y paciente (relacion con la tabla paciente).
A la hora de introducir una patología nueva me da el siguiente error:

```
"Error de sentencia SQL: Error: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`demencia`.`patologias`, CONSTRAINT `sufre` FOREIGN KEY (`paciente`) REFERENCES `paciente` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)"
```

Supongo que tendrá que ver con el diseño de la base de datos.

Para insertar una patología tengo el siguiente código:

```
app.post("/api/paciente/:id/patologias", function(req, res){
    var sql = "INSERT INTO patologias (nombre, paciente)" + 
    " VALUES ('"+ req.body.nombre +"','"+ req.params.id +"')";
    connection.query(sql,function(err,patologia){
        if(err){
            res.status(403).json("Error de sentencia SQL: " + err); 
            return;
        }
        res.status(201).json(patologia);
    });
});
```

Comment: Revisa que el valor de req.params.id esté creado previamente en la tabla paciente